# Read csv file in Apache Spark from remote location (ftp)

Tags: url, ftp, apache-spark

I have a file in a Ubuntu machine which I want to read in Apache spark .

I found this example :

```
object BasicTextFromFTP {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val conf = new SparkConf
      conf.setMaster(args(0))
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val file = sc.textFile("ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ls-LR.gz")
      println(file.collect().mkString("\n"))
    }
}
```

on this link :

> https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicLoadTextFromFTP.scala

I don’t understand how the URL is created. Please help me with this.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic structure of the URL is a schema type (here `ftp`) followed by

```
//<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
```

where every part excluding host can be omitted.