# How do i use a file on FTP in a stand alone spark cluster (pySpark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, ftp, pyspark

Hey i am completely new to spark and recently set up a spark standalone cluster with few laptops.

I have a file shared on my local ftp server with the name new.txt 
According to Spark guide 
"PySpark can create distributed datasets from any storage source supported by Hadoop, including your local file system, HDFS, Cassandra, HBase, Amazon S3, etc"
(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets)

I have opened the pyspark interactive shell in the standalone cluster mode by doing the following:

```
 $ MASTER=spark://IP:PORT ./bin/pyspark
```

and then executed the example commands in the guide.

```
>>> ff= sc.textFile("ftp://192.168.125.124/new.txt")
>>> ans = ff.map(lambda s: len(s)).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

the first line executes fine and rdd is created. after the second line i am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/shrey/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 797, in reduce
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/home/shrey/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/home/shrey/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/home/shrey/spark-1.6.1/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/shrey/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.IOException: Login failed on server - 192.168.125.124, port - 21
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.connect(FTPFileSystem.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.getFileStatus(FTPFileSystem.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:222)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

it says login failed on 192.168.125.124 on port 21. seems like its having some issue returning back the result to ftp ? I cant understand how the result is returned. I accessed my ftp server from browser of the slave computers and it does not prompt for login.My vsftpd.conf has the following permissions set.

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
listen=YES
no_anon_password=YES
anon_root=/srv/ftp
```

When i break the map and reduce part into two different statements like

```
>>> ff= sc.textFile("ftp://192.168.125.124/new.txt")
>>> df = ff.map(lambda s: len(s))
>>> df.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

the map part runs fine but i get the same error on reduce.
I ran other normal jobs which do not require external dataset on my cluster successfully. such as

```
>>> data=[f for x in xrange(10000)]
>>> distData=sc.parallelize(data);
>>>distData.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Please let me now how i could solve this problem and what i am doing wrong. I could use hdfs but i want to know what wrong with using ftp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicLoadTextFromFTP.scala):

Your url should be of the form `ftp://username:password@host/file`. For anonymous login, use `anonymous` as user and password can be anything, it should not be empty.

```
ff= sc.textFile("ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@192.168.125.124/new.txt")
```

And the reason why you are seeing the error only at the reduce part is because `map` is a transformation and `reduce` is an action. An RDD is materialized only when an action is called on it.

Comment: i think my ftp problem solved :) thanks. But the reduce still didnt run. i got a new error saying "seek not supported"
(http://pastebin.com/5NpJk8Dg)

Comment: well, FTPInputStream does not support seek. https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ftp/FTPInputStream.java there is a workaround as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271305/read-file-on-remote-machine-in-apache-spark-using-ftp

Comment: he first downloads the file using addFile and the uses SparkFiles.get to get the location of the file. But that location is the location of the file on my local system. When i went ahead and executed the i got a FileNotFoundException the file would definetly be stored at some other location in the slave systems

Comment: @rajat where you able to fix your issue?

Comment: no, not really.. the error for ftp does not come now. But the get command returns the location where the file was downloaded on my system(master) the file is downloaded on all slave systems also but there location is obviously different .. but it searches for the file on the path where my file got downloaded and returns file not found.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you had two problems :

- how the ftp url was formed
- the seek function not being supported by ftp

The first problem was nicely answered above.

For the seek problem, who might want to look at `sc.wholeTextFiles("ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@192.168.125.124/new.txt")` which will allow you to retrieve the text file as a single string.

Alternatively, you can create an RDD of lines with `sc.wholeTextFiles("ftp://anonymous:pandamagic@192.168.125.124/new.txt").values`

Hope this helps