# Reading large text file from FTP before spark analysis

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am running spark in standalone mode (With a vision to go distributed in future) into my system to do analysis of a very large file > 5 GB. First i need to copy this file from FTP to my local `e.g c:\spark\analysis\bigfile.txt` then i will be able to load the file with spark for analysis.

My question is how can i copy such a big file efficiently without getting out of memory?
Is it possible to do it in spark? Should i use some streaming library like kafka?

The same way i need to write a big file to the ftp server after i complete spark analysis.

Comment: [Read csv file in Apache Spark from remote location (ftp)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34479895/6910411)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple shell command using `Bluezone` or any other edge node connecting terminal emulators :

`cat bigfile.txt | ssh yourUserName@yourServer 'hdfs dfs -put - /pathTo/hdfs'`

It would be bit slower though, but it worked for me for 300GB file.

Note : I have done this because my file was in a server where Hadoop was not installed. If your server has Hadoop installed then you can simply try a `hdfs dfs -put`

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it through stdin:

> Blockquote

wget ftp://user:password@ftpserver/your_file | hadoop fs -put - path_in_hdfs

> Blockquote

The single - tells HDFS put to read from stdin.